# DeMorgans Law Application

Tags: logic

I'm Trying to prove that

**¬(p ↔ q)** is equivalent to **¬p ↔ q**.

I have done the work for ¬p ↔ q and simplified it to **(p ∨ q) ∧ ¬(p ∧ q)** .....My trouble is on the other proposition how do i distribute that not(¬)?

Comment: $\lnot(p\land q)$ is equivalent to $\lnot p \lor \lnot q$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De Morgan's Law: $\neg(p\wedge q) \equiv \neg p\vee\neg q$ and $\neg(p\vee q)\equiv \neg p\wedge \neg q)$

So $\neg(p\leftrightarrow q)~{\equiv \neg((p\to q)\wedge(q\to p))\\\equiv\neg (p\to q)\vee\neg(q\to p)}$

Now, if you do not know how to negate a conditional, first use the equivalence $p\to q\equiv \neg p\vee q$.

$~\\~\\~$

---

PS: Calling DeMorgan's Law "distributing the not" will only confuse you.

Comment: Ok got it! So After applying DeMorgans law to ¬(p ↔ q) is this valid (¬p↔  ¬q)

Comment: No... not at all.

Comment: So where you left off in your answer the negation of the equivalence would be ... P  ∧ ¬ q?

Comment: Yes...  Well, $(p\wedge\neg q)\vee(q\wedge\neg p)$, to be precise.  Then apply distribution and so forth....